# Maintaining a clean environment on a shared computer : automatic data deletion?

Tags: windows, user-accounts, disk-space, restrictions

### Situation :

I'm in a work environment (lab) where we use a **shared computer** (**windows** 10 pro) between teams for some heavy calculations (large RAM, CPU, GPU usage...).

It has been there for about a year, and while I didn't though at the begining it would be efficient for work nor really necessary to force users to read or apply **constraining rules**, or restrict some access though **windows user/drives management** options, I now realize it quite quickly has gotten into a **mess**. The lab seems large enough and with enough turnover so discussions are not sufficient to keep things clean. Moreover, at some point, I will also have to leave, and I wish to implement OS rules that are there to stay, rather than softy guidelines that will be lost (although both are necessary I suppose).

Before trying to decide some rules without knowing their pros and cons on long term, and most of all being quite ignorant on the means to "contain" users perimeter regarding drive access etc, I searched some information over the web and the best I found was **Quotas for user storage**.

It's a good idea but I think something like  an **automatic file deletion system** (only for raw data, wich are supposed to be copies anyway) after an unused time period, on separated accounts wich cannot access each other may be a better solution for flexibility of usage with large datasets and yet ensure a clean environment over the long term.

### The question :

So I wanted to ask experts around here (and i'm sure some had to deal with similar situations) this question :

Do you know if this **automatic file deletion** on non-admin accounts is **feasible with the OS**, in that case windows ? (couldn't find the info)

And if you know if this "maintaining" concern has a more standard name or keyword associated feel free to tell me. :)

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is not what you are looking for, but there is a program called DeepFreeze

https://www.faronics.com/en-uk/products/deep-freeze

It allows you to "freeze" a computer (all changes will be lost after a reboot) and "thaw" it in order to change stuff.

You would need a ***proper*** warning for those using the computer that all things not stored in their own folder (for example on a [NAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network-attached_storage)) will be gone.

Comment: Oh ! Nice, thanks for the tip. Yeah, it seems to be a bit "extreme", but it could be a neat solution if it can be configured to not touch, say a specific hard drive or folder, to allow code, or small processed data to be kept, while wiping automatically raw and large data on any other dedicated space.

Comment: @Osamoele You can allow one or more people to thaw and refreeze the computer (those who behave responsibly) so only they can install stuff. Of course you can tell it to not touch certain folders\partitions https://www.faronics.com/document-library/document/creating-thawspaces-with-deep-freeze You can also redirect user profiles and folders to a Thawed volume  https://www.faronics.com/assets/DF_RetainUserData.pdf

Comment: @Osamoele I don't think a program exists that looks at how big and old a folder is and deletes it if it reaches a certain threshold. But you could write one. It is possible someone will try to hurt you if they suddenly discover their important research project is gone because of software you wrote though.

Comment: @Osamoele Hm, for some reason this exists: http://www.greensy.com/RemoveOldFiles Not sure if it can check file/folder size though

Comment: Wow, thanks so much for digging though the web to help me ! Haha, for the hurting part you are very right. I'll definitely have to make sure every users know about the dangers if I implement any kind of deleting solution like this.

Comment: @Osamoele No problemo. I love marmosets!

Comment: Me too ! But this one is a [Titi](https://cnprc.ucdavis.edu/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/CNPRCtitimonkeys%C2%A9K.West-CNPRC003.jpg) [Monkey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titi) :D